# Windows Task Scheduler can't run a Python script without throwing an error

Tags: python-3.x, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to get a batch file that executes a Python3 script to run on a schedule using Windows 11 Task Scheduler.

The batch file just executes a Python script that writes to an Excel file like this:

```
py WriteToExcel.py
```

Task Scheduler says it runs successfully, and it does execute the batch script, but the Python script always errors out when trying to write to the Excel file.

I have tried using 2 accounts in Task Scheduler to run it:  Me and a new account I created just for this. Both are in the Administrators group.

Both accounts also have full permissions and control over every folder and file in the drive where the script and files are.

I checked and made sure all files are unblocked.

I also tried using the full path and just the file name.

The batch script, Python script, and Excel file are all in the same local folder.

But get this, it always runs perfectly when I execute the bat file from the command line(using the same accounts I mentioned above).

But when I have it run from the Task Scheduler, it starts running, but always errors out in the `try` block of the Python script:

```
try:
    wb = xw.Book("E:\Project\Python\DevResults.xlsx")
     # wb = xw.Book("DevResults.xlsx")
    WriteLog("Writing ", "DevResults.xlsx")
except:
    WriteLog("ERROR ", "Error writing to DevResults")
```

I am unsure what to try next or how to proceed and need some help.  Does anyone have any clue as to what could be the problem?

Here is the full script:

```
# imports
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import xlwings as xw
from UploadData import sftpMethod
from sqlalchemy import text
from  WriteLog import WriteLog

connection_string = "xxx"
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

qry = text("EXECUTE dbo.GatherData")
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)

# load workbook
app = xw.App(visible=False)

try:
    wb = xw.Book("E:\Project\Python\DevResults.xlsx")
    # wb = xw.Book("DevResults.xlsx")
    WriteLog("Writing ", "DevResults.xlsx")
except:
    WriteLog("ERROR ", "Error writing to DevResults")   #ALWAYS AN ERROR

ws = wb.sheets['Dev']

# Update workbook at specified range
ws.range('A2').options(index=False, header=False).value = df

# Close workbook
wb.save()
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Pragmatic_Lee there is no error per se, it just doesn't execute correctly when run by Task Scheduler.  It gets hung up in the `try` block of the Python script.  But if I run it from a command prompt, it runs perfectly.  I am not sure why Task Scheduler is different

Comment: Put the code in your try: segment in a separate file and try running it in a scheduled task. You should be able to see where/what the error is. I suspect it might have something to do with the environment and the path is not valid. Also it’s possible you need to escape the backslashes in the path (\\) or use forward slashes (/).

Comment: Import the logging library to catch the error log